# Pan an UIImageView in background?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, pan

I'm trying to realize an app that requires to move an UIImageView, that is put behind a transparent grid. How can I make it?
This is the code:

```
[[self view] addSubview:myimage];
myimage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[panGesture setDelegate:self];
[myimage addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[self.view addSubview:over];
```

The transparent layer is "over".
If it is not added to the view, my pan method works.
When I add it, nothing works. So, how can I move my image behind the transparent grid?
Thank you everybody.

Comment: in your case add panGestures to over view and handle the moving functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make over not clickable by setting `userInteraction` to no

---

if that doesn't work for some reason, use a custom class for `over` and override `pointInside` to always return NO :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add a`UIImageView` as transparent layer over your image, and as `UIImageView` have by default `userInteractionDisabled` don't change that.

It's because if overlay image have user interaction then that would not let that pass to background view but 'll consume touches. Hence to enable panning on back ground view you need to pass touches on that view. By some approach. One of those is what I told you.